# How to order order cv2 contours in a grid which may have some distortion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have wrote a python file to detect contours in a cv2 grid and order them by going down the columns from left to right. (See grid1 image below).

This is fairly trivial to sort I have pulled the top left corner of the contour and sorted by its `x` then by its `y` coordinate then use the sorted corners to sort the contour list. This works fine when the grid is perfectly straight.

[image: Grid1]

Now if the grid has distortion then this no longer works looking at grid2 we can see that the `x` coordinate of the top left corner of the piece labelled `2` is less than `x` coordinate of the topleft corner of the piece labelled `1` (as shown by the green line).

Hence when I apply my sorting function that worked for grid1 it sorts by `x` then `y` and consequently the piece labelled `2` is incorrectly ordered to be the first element of the sorted contours instead of the second which it should be.

[image: Grid2]

I am looking for a good method to sort both cases correctly.

Anyone have a suggestion(s)?

Comment: Please add some code! I can't really understand what did you want to do.

Comment: Could you explain which part you don't understand I will try and clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may based your ordering selection based both on the distance of a corner for the origin, and the relative corner position.

- Find contours and hierarchy.
  Keep contours with no child (based on hierarchy).
- Find corners of bounding rectangles.

Analyze the corners based on the following conditions (or find more simple conditions):

- Top left contours is the one with the minimum distance of top left corner.
- Bottom right contours is the one with the maximum distance of top left corner.
- Other two contours can be separated by maximum x and maximum y (after eliminating the top left and bottom right).

The solution below, draws bounding rectangles in colors for testing:

1. Red
2. Green
3. Blue
4. Yellow

Here is a working code sample (please read the comments):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read input image as Grayscale
img = cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Convert img to uint8 binary image with values 0 and 255
# All black pixels goes to 0, and other pixels goes to 255
ret, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(img, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find contours in thresh_gray.
cnts, hiers = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2:]  # [-2:] indexing takes return value before last (due to OpenCV compatibility issues).

corners = [] # List of corners
dist = np.array([]) # Array of distance from axes origin

# Iterate cnts and hiers, find bounding rectangles, and add corners to a list
for c, h in zip(cnts, hiers[0]):
    # If contours has no child
    if h[2] == -1:
        # Get bounding rectangle
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        # Append corner to list of corners - format is corners[i] holds a tuple: ((x0, y0), (x1, y1))
        p0 = (x, y)
        p1 = (x+w, y+h)
        corners.append((p0, p1))

        # Distance of corners from origin
        d = np.array([np.linalg.norm(p0), np.linalg.norm(p1)])

        if dist.size == 0:
            dist = d
        else:
            dist = np.vstack((dist, d))


top_left = np.argmin(dist[:,0]) # Index of top left corner (assume minimum distance from origin)
bottom_right = np.argmax(dist[:,1]) # Index of top bottom right corner (assume maximum distance from origin)

tmp_corners = np.array(corners)
tmp_corners[top_left, :, :] = np.array(((0,0), (0,0))) #Ignore top_left corners
tmp_corners[bottom_right, :, :] = np.array(((0,0), (0,0))) #Ignore bottom_right corners
bottom_left = np.argmax(tmp_corners[:,1,1]) #Maximum y is bottom left
tmp_corners[bottom_left, :, :] = np.array(((0,0), (0,0))) #Ignore bottom_left corners
top_right = np.argmax(tmp_corners[:,1,0])  #Maximum x is top right

# Convert Grayscale to BGR (just for testing - for drawing rectangles in green color).
out = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Draw rectangles (for testing)
# 1. Red
# 2. Green
# 3. Blue
# 4. Yellow
cv2.rectangle(out, corners[top_left][0], corners[top_left][1], (0, 0, 255), thickness = 2)
cv2.rectangle(out, corners[bottom_left][0], corners[bottom_left][1], (0, 255, 0), thickness = 2)
cv2.rectangle(out, corners[top_right][0], corners[top_right][1], (255, 0, 0), thickness = 2)
cv2.rectangle(out, corners[bottom_right][0], corners[bottom_right][1], (0, 255, 255), thickness = 2)

cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)  #Save out to file (for testing).


# Show result (for testing).
cv2.imshow('thresh_gray', thresh_gray)
cv2.imshow('out', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer I haven't got time to review and try to implement to my code but will have a look and accept next week if all goes well :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did work for the `2x2` grid. Unfortunately I wanted something that would work for an `nxm` grid for natural numbers n,m. I did however come up with a general solution that involves sorting and subsorting. I am accepting this answer as it did work for the question as stated though.